# Select column, if blank select another column else ' ' if BOTH are null

Tags: sql, case, isnull

Using SQL Server, I would like to have a field print out as blank rather than 'null'.  The query is to first pick up phone number from one table - if null then it picks up from another table.  If both are null, then I would like to have it return ' ' (blank) rather than 'null'.

I have tried multiple things in the 2nd line but still get nulls instead of blanks to print.

```sql
SELECT case when dbo.vwPersonDistinctPhone.phone IS NULL THEN PERSONAL_PHONE_NUMBER 

when (dbo.vwPersonDistinctPhone.phone is null and PERSONAL_PHONE_NUMBER is null)  then ' '

else dbo.vwPersonDistinctPhone.phone END AS 'phone',
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i dont think you need the second when, you should be able to just to do this, there is a isnull function in sql server that if the value is null then it replaces it with the second parameter. So in this case if personal_phone_number is null then it will be '' or personal_phone_number if is not.

```
SELECT case when dbo.vwPersonDistinctPhone.phone IS NULL THEN ISNULL(PERSONAL_PHONE_NUMBER, '') else dbo.vwPersonDistinctPhone.phone END AS 'phone',
```